# Do we have mobile apps which uses an action button like placement on top of the bottom navbar?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, interface, experience

[image]

Please checkout the attachment. I have seen many such designs with the action button popping out from the bottom nav bar. Is it practically possible to add such buttons, and if yes, please provide actual examples of the same. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen similar designs but the middle button is actually part of the navbar. A shadow underneath the button is quite confusing.

Comment: Can you please mention real time apps, that use similar navbars? Thanks :)

Comment: Carousell is one pop-up in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox IOS mobile UI uses a similar kind of navigation metjod. I have attached the screenshot. [image]